# Is there a computable enumeration of a set of all computable functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$?

Tags: computability

Consider the set $F$ of all functions from natural numbers to natural numbers (possibly with undefined points) which are computable (implementable in python). Does there exist an enumeration of them $F=\{f_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such the function $g(i, x) := f_i(x)$ is computable?

I know that if we allowed repetitions in the enumeration, the answer would be *yes* via the universal machine (enumerating algorithms instead of functions is possible).

I know that if we did not allow undefined points, the answer would be *no* via the diagonal argument on function $g'(x):=g(x, x) + 1$ which would have to be computable but could not coincide with any $f_i$.

However, I can't figure out the middle case. My hunch is that the answer is *no*.

Comment: Such a set is uncountable. Hence there does not exist any enumeration of it.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Note that the *body* of the question specifies that the functions in question are computable. To the OP, you should make the body match the title (or vice versa); the two questions at present are quite different.

Comment: @NoahSchweber What are you referring to? Is there another meaning for computable enumeration of functions?

Comment: I see. Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that the title question does not match the body. I'll answer the question in the body, since the title question is trivial.*

Perhaps surprisingly, the answer is **yes**! That is:

> There is a partial computable binary function $f(x,y)$ such that for all partial computable unary functions $g(x)$ there is **exactly one** $n$ with $$g(-)\simeq f(-,n).$$

Such an $f$ is called a **Friedberg enumeration** (or **numbering**); the existence of Friedberg enumerations was first proved by (unsurprisingly) Friedberg, but a simpler argument was later [given by Kummer](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397590901414). I've written a bit more about these [at CSSE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116704/language-to-define-perfectly-a-programming-problem/116708#116708) and [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361862/what-are-some-examples-of-theorem-requiring-highly-subtle-hypothesis/361870#361870).

Comment: I am happy I topped up your collection of SE sites where you featured this nice result :)